# Slow script execution

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I use a MSGraph PowerShell script to extract certain information from our users' O365 accounts.
The script runs fine for the first dozen users or so, then seems to stall for a minute or few then resume normally for the next dozen or so users and so on.
I'd like to know if there's a way to speed up the execution. The execution speed is fine until extracting the SignInActivity. That's where things get bogged down. The problem lines are below.

```
@{Label = "Last Sign On"; Expression = {
    #Expression variables
    $GUID = $_.Id
    $GetSignOn = Get-MgUser -UserId $GUID -Property SignInActivity | `
    Select-Object {$_.SignInActivity} -ExpandProperty SignInActivity | Select-Object LastSignInDateTime
    #Extract desired data from array
    $LastSignOn = $GetSignOn.LastSignInDateTime -split " "
    $LastSignOn[0]
    }
```

I've removed the SignInActivity request from the script and it runs without pauses and at a decent pace.
Clarifying the question, Can I speed up the execution of the portion of the script which pulls users' SignInActivity and if so, how?
The full code is below.

```
#Connect to Microsoft Graph with Required Scopes
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All","Directory.Read.All","AuditLog.Read.All"

#Switch to Beta version to access Last Sign On Properties
Select-MgProfile beta

#DateStamp and Path for Output file
$LogDate = Get-Date -Format "dd-MMM-yyyy"
$Path = "C:\Scripts\MSGraph\ADUsers\CTS Licensed Users_$LogDate.csv"

#Define Properties for UserReport
$Properties = @(
    'GivenName', 'DisplayName', 'JobTitle', 'UserPrincipalName', 'CompanyName', 'Department', 'MobilePhone', 'BusinessPhones', 'OfficeLocation', `
    'StreetAddress', 'City', 'State', 'OtherMails', 'EmployeeId', 'Manager', 'CreatedDateTime', 'EmployeeHireDate', 'Id', 'SignInActivity', 'AssignedLicenses'
)

#Define Filter Variables for Users with Paid O365 Subscription
$StdLicense = "f245ecc8-75af-4f8e-b61f-27d8114de5f3"
$PremLicense = "cbdc14ab-d96c-4c30-b9f4-6ada7cdc1d46"

#Define Filter Variable to exclude IT Helpdesk
$IT = "IT Helpdesk"

#Structure Filter as a Script Block
$UserReport = Get-MgUser -Filter "AccountEnabled eq true" -Property $Properties | Where-Object {
    ( ($_.AssignedLicenses.SkuId -eq $StdLicense) -or ($_.AssignedLicenses.SkuId -eq $PremLicense) -and ($_.DisplayName -ne $IT ) )
}

Write-Host -f Yellow "PowerShell is Preparing:"
Write-Host -f Yellow "CTS Licensed User Report"

#Build Hashtable and Populate Properties
$UserReport | Sort-Object GivenName | Select-Object `
@{Label = "Full Name"; Expression = { $_.DisplayName } },
@{Label = "Job Title"; Expression = { $_.JobTitle } },
@{Label = "Company Email"; Expression = { $_.UserPrincipalName } },
@{Label = "Company"; Expression = { $_.CompanyName } },
@{Label = "Department"; Expression = { $_.Department } },
@{Label = "Mobile Phone"; Expression = { $_.MobilePhone } },
@{Label = "Office Phone"; Expression = { $_.BusinessPhones } },
@{Label = "Office Address"; Expression = { $_.OfficeLocation } },
@{Label = "Employee Street"; Expression = { $_.StreetAddress } },
@{Label = "Employee City"; Expression =  { $_.City } },
@{Label = "Employee State"; Expression = { $_.State } },
@{Label = "Personal Email"; Expression = { $_.OtherMails } },
@{Label = "EIN"; Expression = { $_.EmployeeId } },
@{Label = "Manager Name"; Expression =  {
    #Expression variables
    $UserId = $_.UserPrincipalName
    $ManagerArry = Get-MgUser -UserId $UserId -ExpandProperty Manager | `
    Select-Object {$_.Manager.AdditionalProperties.displayName}
    #Extract desired data from array
    $splitName = $ManagerArry -Split "="
    $ManagerName = $splitName -split "}"
    $ManagerName[1]
    } },
@{Label = "Manager Email"; Expression = {
    #Expression variables
    $UserId = $_.UserPrincipalName
    $MailArry = Get-MgUser -UserId $UserId -ExpandProperty Manager | `
    Select-Object {$_.Manager.AdditionalProperties.userPrincipalName}
    #Extract desired data from array
    $splitMail = $MailArry -Split "="
    $ManagerMail = $splitMail -Split"}"
    $ManagerMail[1]
    } },
@{Label = "Account Created"; Expression = {
    #Expression variables
    $CreatedOn = $_.CreatedDateTime
    #Extract desired data from array
    $SplitTime = $CreatedOn -Split " "
    $CreatedDate = $SplitTime -Split "="
    $CreatedDate[0] } },
@{Label = "Hire Date"; Expression = {
    #Expression variables 
    $HiredOn = $_.EmployeeHireDate
    #Extract desired data from array
    $NoHireTime = $HiredOn -Split " "
    $HireDate = $NoHireTime -Split "="
    $HireDate[0] } },
@{Label = "License"; Expression = {
    #Expression variables
    $UserId = $_.UserPrincipalName
    $GetLicenses = Get-MgUserLicenseDetail -UserId $UserId | Select-Object SkuPartNumber
    $GetLicenses.SkuPartNumber -join ','
    } },
@{Label = "Last Sign On"; Expression = {
    #Indicate Progress
    Write-Host "Exporting User Details for"$_.DisplayName
    #Expression variables
    $GUID = $_.Id
    $GetSignOn = Get-MgUser -UserId $GUID -Property SignInActivity | `
    Select-Object {$_.SignInActivity} -ExpandProperty SignInActivity | Select-Object LastSignInDateTime
    #Extract desired data from array
    $LastSignOn = $GetSignOn.LastSignInDateTime -split " "
    $LastSignOn[0]
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path $Path -NoTypeInformation

Write-Host -f Yellow "Success!"
Write-Host -f Yellow "Report Saved to:" $Path
```

Comment: Your expression is overly complicated, can be simplified to just `E ={ (Get-MgUser -UserId $_.Id -Property SignInActivity).SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime }` however if you want to improve the efficiency of the code will need the code itself not just part of it. You also need to be aware that the Graph API can throw a "TooManyRequests" exception which must be awaited before a subsequent call, all this process is already automatically handled by `Get-MgUser`.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What do you need help with?

Comment: Thanks Santiago. Using your simplification, the script ran to the first pause as usual then seems to have hung. It did eventually resume but hasn't sped things along. I'd be happy to post the entire code. I guess just drop it in a comment?

Comment: Edit the question and all code there, comment section is for comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE**

Since I see that you have `Select-MgProfile beta` in your code, most likely you're using an old version of this Module, in latest version the cmdlets targeting `beta` and `v1.0` endpoints have been divided into 2 different Modules, now for beta you would use [`Get-MgBetaUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.beta.users/get-mgbetauser?view=graph-powershell-beta) without a need for `Select-MgProfile`.

Consider updating your Module with:

```bash
Update-Module Microsoft.Graph
```

And installing the [`beta`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Beta/2.11.1) version with:

```bash
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Graph.Beta
```

---

There is a lot that can be improved from your current code, the main issues are many Graph calls for the same user to get information you already have, i.e. **`Get-MgUser -UserId $UserId -ExpandProperty Manager` is being called twice, to get the Manager's `displayName` and `mail` when the API call could be just one**. The other inefficiency comes when calling `Get-MgUserLicenseDetail` for each user when what you could do instead is create a map of all `SkuID` and their corresponding `SkuPartNumber` using [`Get-MgSubscredSku -All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.directorymanagement/get-mgsubscribedsku?view=graph-powershell-1.0).

Filtering all users with:

```bash
Where-Object {
    $_.AssignedLicenses.SkuId -eq $StdLicense -or 
    $_.AssignedLicenses.SkuId -eq $PremLicense -and
    $_.DisplayName -ne $IT
}
```

Can be replaced by filtering server side, with the OData filter, i.e.:

```
displayName ne '$IT' and
(assignedLicenses/any(e:e/skuId eq $StdLicense) or
assignedLicenses/any(e:e/skuId eq $PremLicense))
```

Finally, the use of `Select-Object` and its horrible syntax for calculated properties makes the code unreadable, its recommended to use [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.4) instead.

The final code becomes:

```
# definitions of `$Properties`, `$StdLicense`, `$premLicense` and others
# remains the same here

$skuMap = @{}
Get-MgSubscribedSku -All | ForEach-Object {
    $skuMap[$_.SkuId] = $_.SkuPartNumber
}
$getMgUserSplat = @{
    Filter           = -join @(
        "accountEnabled eq true and "                         # All Enabled user accounts
        "displayName ne '$IT' and "                           # Where their displayName is not `$IT`
        "(assignedLicenses/any(e:e/skuId eq $StdLicense) or " # and any of their assigned licenses
        "assignedLicenses/any(e:e/skuId eq $PremLicense))"    # is either `$StdLicense` or `$PremLicense`
    )
    Property         = $Properties
    ConsistencyLevel = 'eventual'
    CountVariable    = 'count'
    All              = $true
}

Get-MgUser @getMgUserSplat | ForEach-Object {
    $managerEmail = $managerName = $null
    $manager = (Get-MgUserManager -UserId $_.Id -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).AdditionalProperties
    if ($manager) {
        $managerName = $manager['displayName']
        $managerEmail = $manager['mail']
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        'Full Name'       = $_.DisplayName
        'Job Title'       = $_.JobTitle
        'Company Email'   = $_.UserPrincipalName
        'Company'         = $_.CompanyName
        'Department'      = $_.Department
        'Mobile Phone'    = $_.MobilePhone
        'Office Phone'    = $_.BusinessPhones -join ', '
        'Office Address'  = $_.OfficeLocation
        'Employee Street' = $_.StreetAddress
        'Employee City'   = $_.City
        'Employee State'  = $_.State
        'Personal Email'  = $_.OtherMails -join ', '
        'EIN'             = $_.EmployeeId
        'Manager Name'    = $managerName
        'Manager Email'   = $managerEmail
        'Account Created' = $_.CreatedDateTime
        'Hire Date'       = $_.EmployeeHireDate
        'License'         = $skuMap[$_.AssignedLicenses.SkuId] -join ', '
        'Last Sign On'    = $_.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime
    }
} | Export-Csv $Path -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you again Santiago. Tested and works Much Faster than the originally (poorly) written script. I tried some of what you included initially. But was off track somewhere and reverted to what I knew. Will spend some time and testing to ensure I understand the improvements and impacts.

Comment: I forgot to mention since I see that you have `Select-MgProfile beta`, most likely you're using an old version of this module, in latest version the `beta` and `v1.0` cmdlet have been divided into 2 different modules, now for beta you would use `Get-MgBetaUser`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.beta.users/get-mgbetauser?view=graph-powershell-beta @SimpleMan